# HTML.EditorFor renders nested class properties without id

Tags: asp.net-mvc

This is an ASP.Net web application, a hybrid of webforms and MVC v5.2.3.  When I call Html.EditorFor on properties of the nested class the inputs render without an "id" attribute.  How come? And is there anything I can change in the model to force asp.net to render an "id" attribute?

My model, "Parent", contains a nested class, "Child":

```
public class Parent
{
    public string ParentName {get;set;}

    public class _Child
    {
        public string ChildName {get;set;}
    }

    public Child _Child {get;set;}
}
```

On the view, when I render Parent.ParentName using Html.EditorFor(), it renders with both the "Name" and "Id" attributes.  In other words, when I put this in the *.cshtml file:

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.ParentName)
```

It renders the following HTML:

```
<input id="ParentName" name="ParentName" type="text" value="" />
```

However, when I render Parent._Child.ChildName, it renders without the "Id" attribute.  In other words, when I put this in the *.cshtml file:

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m._Child.ChildName)
```

It renders the following HTML, without the "id" attribute:

```
<input name="_Child.ChildName" type="text" value="" />
```

How come? And can I do anything I the model to force generation of "id"?  I realize I can add it myself using new HtmlAttributes and so on.

Comment: Why do not you create a input with hidden class for id?

Comment: Change the `_Child` to start with a letter perhaps?

Comment: Thank you @MarkSchultheiss, that was indeed the problem.  Could you please change your comment to an answer? Then I can select it and guide future generations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This uses the HTML 4 specification https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/types.html#case-sensitive which says that is must start with a letter, change the underscore to a letter and it should be OK.

Purely opinion but I would not use an underscore here anyway simply because it is harder to type.